# How perform has_child query for examples in ES 6.0

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/parent-join.html#_searching_with_parent_join) is en examples about `join` type in elasticsearch. I have insert mapping, parents and children:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "my_join_field": {
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "question": "answer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT my_index/doc/1?refresh
{
  "text": "This is a question",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "question"
  }
}

PUT my_index/doc/2?refresh
{
  "text": "This is a another question",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "question"
  }
}

PUT my_index/doc/1?refresh
{
  "text": "This is a question",
  "my_join_field": "question"
}

PUT my_index/doc/2?refresh
{
  "text": "This is another question",
  "my_join_field": "question"
}
```

Now I am trying to search for parents by children:

```
GET /my_index/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "my_join_field",
      "query": {
        "match" : {
          "text": "question"
        }
      },
      "ignore_unmapped": true
    }
  },
  "highlight" : {
    "fields" : {
      "content" : {}
    }
  }
}
```

And I got no results. :( >:(

First of all what `type` fields should be??? They are told that [types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html) are removed
Second, I have to add `ignore_unmapped` (look [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-query-multiple-indexes-in-elasticsearch-5-6-when-they-have-different-parent-child-mappings/105300)) and still no results

So how to find parent by `has_child` query for data in elasticsearch example?

Comment: Did  you figure this out?

Comment: Yes look at my answer. There are yaml file, feel free to ask any clarifying questions in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [11_parent_child.yml](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/950c4363bfe45a676e74ac68eaaec3da0ad499b3/modules/parent-join/src/test/resources/rest-api-spec/test/11_parent_child.yml) file. It contains indexing of parent, child and performs query for children. It is `yaml` but I think conversion to `json` is obvious.